# WNetAddConnection2 create too many socket in windows server 2008 HPC Edition

Tags: c, windows, network-programming

I call WNetAddConnection2 many times without WNetCancelConnection2, I just check its return value. This works in windows server 2003, only create one connection, but in windows server 2008, it created too many connection. What's the problem?

EDIT - code as per comment:

```
TCHAR szLocalName[32] = _T("t:"), szRemoteName[MAX_PATH] = _T("\\\\ws2008_1\\sample_share");

// Assign our values to the NETRESOURCE structure. 
nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY; 
nr.lpLocalName = szLocalName; 
nr.lpRemoteName = szRemoteName; 
nr.lpProvider = NULL; 

// Call the WNetAddConnection2 function to assign 
// a drive letter to the share. 
dwRetVal = WNetAddConnection2(&nr, 0, 0, FALSE);
```

Output is:

```
mount <x:> to <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> with :0 PID:8956
mount <x:> to <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> with :0 PID:7284
remote name is <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> and errCode is: 85 PID:8592
remote name is <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> and errCode is: 85 PID:4196
remote name is <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> and errCode is: 85 PID:7708
remote name is <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> and errCode is: 85 PID:7028
remote name is <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> and errCode is: 85 PID:3988
remote name is <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> and errCode is: 85 PID:3680
remote name is <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> and errCode is: 85 PID:6364
remote name is <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> and errCode is: 85 PID:7764
mount <x:> to <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> with :0 PID:8764
mount <x:> to <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> with :0 PID:4692
mount <x:> to <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> with :0 PID:4996
mount <x:> to <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> with :0 PID:5300
mount <x:> to <\\ws2008_1\sample_share_2> with :0 PID:6028
```

Note: the process was created by CreateProcessAsUser, the user name is the same. From the log message, it works sometimes, is it logon session related?

Thanks

Dma

Comment: More infomation: I call this function in different processes. Will it affect the result? And another strange thing: I can't see driver name in "Computer".

Comment: the point is more: what are the parameters you call it with ? how often ? what is the reason you call it often ? are processes for example in different sessions/terminal server connections ? any reason why you don't call `WNetCancelConnection2` ?

Comment: At some time point, there are more than 30 process call this function at the same PC with the same parameters. It's a distributed system that use shared folders to exchange result.

Comment: the processes on the same pc reside on the same desktop or are they running with different users ?

Comment: They are the same users.

Comment: @Yahia, I recheck the code. the function call is " WNetAddConnection2(&nr, 0, 0, FALSE);", the dwFlags is FALSE. Is it the reason?

Comment: not sure but I think the design is flawed - according to your code you always map to "t:"... so why not check if "t:" is already there and only execute this code if it is not ?

Comment: @Yahia because I don't known whether the "t:" is mapped to right remoted host. I need use WNetAddConnection2 to check .

Comment: And I didn't set "nr" to zero. I think this should be the problem.

Comment: the way you describe it you are not checking, you are telling the system to map it... if it is already mapped (perhaps to the wrong host) the system won't change that existing mapping upon your call... for checking you would use `WNetGetConnection` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385453%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and compare the returned `lpRemoteName` with your "right host"... if it is not you would need to Cancel the existing connection before making a new one!

Comment: @Yahia, your method works, but I'm fixing a bug, I can't change too much code.

Comment: I understand that BUT even without the "too many sockets"-error your method fails when "t:" is already mapped to the wrong host... so the bug is even there when it "worked" on Windows 2003

Comment: Here are many processes, so two processes may consider it's un-mounted at the same time.

Comment: if two proceses consider it is unmounted at the same time and they try to mount it at the same is not really good but better than it is now... IF you want to make that "bulletproof" you would wrap the mounting code into a global/named Mutex (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so that only one process would try the mount at any given time... outside AND within the Mutex you first check if it is already mounted and only try the mount when it is not...

Comment: hi @Yahia, I got the message as I append just now. Those processes were created by CreateProcessAsUser, is it session related issue? The OS is windows server 2008 HPC.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages is NOT session related... it says `ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This means the method you use to mount has been called more than one time in that session (different parts of your application, multiple instances of the application in same session, restarted application in same session...).

Your method to do so is flawed - you need to:

- make sure that within the same session only one process tries a mount for example with a named `Mutex` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- check before trying to mount if the respective drive letter is already in use see `WNetGetConnection` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385453%28v=VS.85%29.aspx and if it perhaps is mapped to the correct share (return value `lpRemoteName`)
- when the session ends/the application ends you need to dismount see `WNetCancelConnection2` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385427%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

There are other points to make sure... but they depend on the answers to the following questions:

- Does the application run within the same session multiple times ?
- Does the application try the mount in different parts of the application ?
- Is this a TerminalServer environment ?